# jQuery addclass/remove Class work once

Tags: jquery

I have this action on click :

```
$(".sp-left, .sp-right").each(function(){
    var el = $(this);

    if (el.hasClass('sp-left')) {
        el.removeClass("sp-left").addClass("sp-right");
    } else {
        el.removeClass("sp-right").addClass("sp-left");
    }    
});
```

there is multi stepform with jquery, it works fine but when i switch between steps these codes not working ??

Comment: Where's the click handler, what does "step" mean, and there is a `toggleClass` method available ?

Comment: steps are in partail view with angular, i know there is a toggleClass

Comment: So why not just `$(".sp-left, .sp-right").toggleClass("sp-left sp-right")`

Comment: i put this for better understanding for you guys but in my code i've used toggle

Comment: Well, if it works, but doesn't work "between steps", adding the steps to the question somehow would probably be a good idea, there's not much we can do with code that does what it's supposed to ?

Comment: I know some, and I know what a multi step form is, but I don't see how that helps me understand what the issue is ?

Answer (score 0):

Right way to use each **.each(function(index, element)** is this by $(this) u will not get the element

```
   $(".sp-left, .sp-right").click(function(e){


      var el = $(element);

      console.log(el);

       if (el.hasClass('sp-left')) {
         el.removeClass("sp-left").addClass("sp-right");
        } else {
          el.removeClass("sp-right").addClass("sp-left");
       }    

     });
```

Comment: by $(this) i dnt know but you will get the all elements with classname .sp-left and .sp-right .. i am not sure abt it... but my way of using each is good...!! try it..!!i hope it will work...!!

Comment: what do u mean by adding all html ?

Comment: add all html with the jquery click action...!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68171/discussion-between-user3642164-and-jaimin-moslake).